# Interpolating in R restricted by a character variable

Tags: r, interpolation, zoo

I have a data set that consists of an ID, years and an index:

```
ID = c("ABW", "ABW", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "GER", "GER", "GER")
year = c(2000, 2005, 2000, 2002, 2008, 2005, 2008, 2010)
index = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 8, NA, 6, NA)

df <- data.frame(ID, year, index)
```

I am trying to interpolate the missing values in the index but I want the interpolation to be restricted by the ID - e.g. I want R to interpolate the index for all rows with the ID "FRA" and then start the interpolation over again for all rows with the ID "GER". And if there are no values at all for a specific ID (like for the ID "ABW") then I want R to return no interpolated values either.

I have tried this code (but it does not take the ID into consideration):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(index = na.approx(index, rule = 2)
```

After the interpolation I want my index column to look like this:

```
index = c(NA, NA, 4, 6, 8, 6, 6, 6)
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Use group by i.e. `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(index = na.approx(index, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 2)) %>% fill(index, .direction = 'updown')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811638/interpolation-extrapolation-by-group-in-r